# Why does MsgBox require a byte variable [VBA]

Tags: vba, excel

When displaying a simple MsgBox, such as:

```
MsgBox("Hello World!")
```

works fine, why does a little bit more "advanced" MessageBox has to be written this way:

```
Dim DisplayMsgBox as Byte
DisplayMsgBox = MsgBox("Hello world!", vbOKOnly, "Say Hi")
```

Is there any special reason why this has to be done this way and not just like a "normal" MsgBox without any "extra attachments"? (so like this:)

```
MsgBox("Hello world!", vbOKOnly, "Say Hi")
```

Comment: You can do `MsgBox "Hello world!", vbOKOnly, "Say Hi"` the `()` are required when using `=`.

Comment: If you like the `()` then put `Call` in front `Call MsgBox("Hello world!", vbOKOnly, "Say Hi")`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick answer. Now i have three new methods to express something :) @ScottCraner

Answer (score 2):

The return type isn't a `Byte` per se, but a `vbMsgBoxResult` enum value.

MSDN docs are getting harder and harder to find, but anyway with [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com) you get a commandbar that features a context-sensitive label that confirms the return type:

[image: Rubberduck commandbar]

That's coming from actually loading the project's referenced COM libraries and iterating the COM types and their members (I own the Rubberduck repository).

`vbMsgBoxResult` being an `Enum`, the underlying type is a `Long`, not a `Byte` - you can easily confirm this in the immediate pane:

```
?TypeName(VbMsgBoxResult.vbOK)
Long
```

---

As for the parentheses, there's nothing special about `MsgBox` - it's the same syntax as any other `Function` procedure.

The reason this works:

```
MsgBox ("Test")
```

Is because you're forcing the string argument `"Test"` to be passed by value (that's that the parens do!)

And the reason this doesn't work:

```
MsgBox ("Test", vbOkOnly)
```

Is because VBA can't evaluate `"Test", vbOkOnly` as one single argument to be passed `ByVal` to the function.

This would work:

```
MsgBox ("Test"), (vbOkOnly)
```

But would look silly.

When calling a VBA `Function` like you would a `Sub` (i.e. when you don't care about the returned value), you need to drop the parentheses, or use the [obsolete] explicit `Call` syntax:

```
Call MsgBox("Test", vbOkOnly)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use:

```
Dim DisplayMsgBox as Byte
DisplayMsgBox = MsgBox("Hello world!", vbOKOnly, "Say Hi")
```

`DisplayMsgBox` will get the value of the button pressed

Try this and have a look to the differences:

```
Sub Test_MsgBox_Result()
Dim DisplayMsgBox As Byte
DisplayMsgBox = MsgBox("Hello world!", vbOKOnly, "Say Hi")
MsgBox "The value of Ok is " & DisplayMsgBox
DisplayMsgBox = MsgBox("Hello world!", vbYesNo, "Say Hi")
If DisplayMsgBox = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "The value of Yes is " & DisplayMsgBox
Else
    MsgBox "The value of No is " & DisplayMsgBox
End If
DisplayMsgBox = MsgBox("Hello world!", vbYesNoCancel, "Say Hi")
If DisplayMsgBox = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "The value of Yes is " & DisplayMsgBox
ElseIf DisplayMsgBox = vbNo Then
    MsgBox "The value of No is " & DisplayMsgBox
Else
    MsgBox "The value of Cancel is " & DisplayMsgBox
End If
End Sub
```

For more informations have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that really helps a lot :)